# module/theme update on web hosted site question

Tags: console

I am new to drupal and I just installed a fresh site onto Acquia web hosting. How do I install modules and themes since I can't seem to be given direct access to the file manager via the browser? Terminal/console from my desktop? Use Drush? What is the simpliest route?

(please don't ding me for asking what may appear as a subjective question, I just need the most secure way to doing it that is simple!).

Answer (score 0):

Straight from [the docs](https://docs.acquia.com/acquia-cloud/develop/install-module):

> If your application is hosted on Acquia Cloud, the module directories are part of the code repository, which is not directly writable. This means that you can't directly add a module using the Update Manager, drush dl, or SFTP. Instead, you must commit your changes using a version control system (Git).

So you need to commit the modules to git locally, and push them to the repo; Acquia’s platform will take care of the rest.

The same docs explain the various specific implementation options in step-by-step guides.